# Adding +1 to each class in a foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm using WordPress for the site.
I have the pasted loop below that I would like to add +1 to each of the output id names.

So the current ID is id="plan1_price"
After each loop I would like it to become id="plan2_price", id="plan3_price" etc...

```
    <table class="
                <?php
                $best = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_bestcss' );
                if (!empty($best)){  echo "highlight-best-" . rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_bestcss' ) . " ";  }
                $popular = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_popularcss' );
                if (!empty($popular)){ echo "highlight-popular-" . rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_popularcss' ); } 
                ?>
            " border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <?php 
                        $tableheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_heading', 'type=text' );
                        foreach ( $tableheading as $index => $heading ) { 
                    ?>
                    <th scope="col"> 
                    <h3><?php echo $heading; ?></h3>
                        <p class="sub-heading">
                        <?php 
                                $tablesub = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading' );
                                if (!empty($tablesub)) {
                                    $tablesubheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading', 'type=text' );
                                    echo $tablesubheading[$index];
                                } 
                            ?>
                        </p>
<!--
    THIS IS THE ID i WOULD LIKE TO ADD +1 TO -- id="plan1_price"
-->
                        <div id="plan1_price" class="price">
                            <sup>$</sup>
                            <span class="amount">
                                <?php 
                                    $tableprice = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_price_heading' );
                                    if (!empty($tableprice)) {
                                        $tablepriceheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_price_heading', 'type=text' );
                                        echo $tablepriceheading[$index];
                                    } 
                                ?>
                            </span>
                            <small class="per-period">/mo</small>
                        </div>
                        </th>
                    <?php 
                        } 
                    ?>
                </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `id="plan1_price_<?= $plan1_price_id++ ?>"` ?

Comment: @FoxRider you should never suggest to another user to use PHP short tags, not all servers / setups will have this enabled

Comment: @DannyBroadbent `<?=` is save to use and "always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting"; see http://php.net/basic-syntax.phptags

Comment: @FoxRider : PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

Comment: @DannyBroadbent I know that, and I never denied that. What I was trying to point out is, while `<?` is **not** available when `short_open_tag=Off`, the short-echo tag `<?=` **is** and will **always** be available (according to the official PHP documentation mentioned above). So, `<?` is indeed bad practise, but `<?=` is absolutely okay. Anyway, you may be right - it may confuse beginners. I'll consider this for the future. :)

Comment: @FoxRider Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available. Legacy versions of PHP (which many users are still on) will not have this available by default. Not everyone can be up to date with PHP (some have huge systems that can take months to change across, some prefer the older PHP code as they haven't adjusted to the new changes). Thats all I mean. It's great to advise of new updates/changes but i wouldn't use it unless you know they are using it themselves.

Comment: @DannyBroadbent That's a valid point I totally missed there. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @FoxRider No problem, you just don't want to answer someones question and be penalised because it causes the user more errors rather than answering the question to their specific needs / setup, same with ones still using mysql instead of mysqli or pdo i advise it but still answer to the issue at hand

Comment: @DannyBroadbent Yea, you're right, and I absolutely support your approach. I just didn't take notice that it's only valid for PHP >= 5.4.0. My fault. :( Luckily, though, comments can't get down votes. ^^

Comment: No worries :) now you know and lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a $count and increment it on each loop:

```
<table class="
                <?php
                $count=1;
                $best = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_bestcss' );
                if (!empty($best)){  echo "highlight-best-" . rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_bestcss' ) . " ";  }
                $popular = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_popularcss' );
                if (!empty($popular)){ echo "highlight-popular-" . rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_popularcss' ); } 
                ?>
            " border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <?php 
                        $tableheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_heading', 'type=text' );
                        foreach ( $tableheading as $index => $heading ) { 
                    ?>
                    <th scope="col"> 
                    <h3><?php echo $heading; ?></h3>
                        <p class="sub-heading">
                        <?php 
                                $tablesub = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading' );
                                if (!empty($tablesub)) {
                                    $tablesubheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading', 'type=text' );
                                    echo $tablesubheading[$index];
                                } 
                            ?>
                        </p>
<!--
    THIS IS THE ID i WOULD LIKE TO ADD +1 TO -- id="plan1_price"
-->
                        <div id="plan<?php echo $count; ?>_price" class="price">
                            <sup>$</sup>
                            <span class="amount">
                                <?php 
                                    $tableprice = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_price_heading' );
                                    if (!empty($tableprice)) {
                                        $tablepriceheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_price_heading', 'type=text' );
                                        echo $tablepriceheading[$index];
                                    } 
                                ?>
                            </span>
                            <small class="per-period">/mo</small>
                        </div>
                        </th>
                    <?php
                            $count++;
                        } 
                    ?>
                </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, ill accept your answer in a couple of mins.

Comment: How can I make the first iteration output a no.1

Comment: is that with the <sup>$</sup> tags

Comment: sorry no, the first id is being output like so `id="plan_price"` the second like so `id="plan2_price"`

Comment: At the top did you see the <?php
                $count=1;

Comment: ha, no... you're a genius. Thanks Danny.